# depth_image_proc not working with custom depth

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, depth-image-proc

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm trying to modify a depth image from Realsense camera and generate a point cloud with the modified depth.

What I've done is (sorry for the links. I couldn't upload snippets properly):

1. Launch Realsense camera ros wrapper as
   `roslaunch realsense2_camera rs_camera.launch align_depth:=true image_fps:=5 depth_fps:=5`
2. Write a python code that modifies depth image from camera; see [image_converter.py](https://github.com/JinraeKim/myros/blob/ae12a19f5a11ed6bef405ce8195228699044eb4e/depth_converter.py).
3. Run a launch file based on [depth_image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/depth_image_proc#Execution); see [point_cloud_xyzrgb_depth_converted.launch](https://github.com/JinraeKim/myros/blob/ae12a19f5a11ed6bef405ce8195228699044eb4e/point_cloud_xyzrgb_depth_converted.launch)

In rviz, I couldn't see any point cloud as shown [here](https://github.com/JinraeKim/myros/blob/ae12a19f5a11ed6bef405ce8195228699044eb4e/for_ros_answers.png).

Note that if I change the topic name of depth image that `point_clound_xyzrgb_depth_converted.launch` subscribes, I can see the point cloud.

Anyone has a comment for this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/405534/depth_image_proc-not-working-with-custom-depth/) by [iHany](https://answers.ros.org/users/92871/ihany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2022-08-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set the header of your image message as shown below. The original code taken from [your shared reference](https://github.com/JinraeKim/myros/blob/ae12a19f5a11ed6bef405ce8195228699044eb4e/depth_converter.py#L18-L40).

```
    ...
    self.depth_sub = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw", Image, self.callback)

def callback(self, depth_data):
    try:
        cv_depth = self.bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(depth_data, "16UC1")
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
    
    (rows, cols) = cv_depth.shape
    cv_depth[0:int(rows/2), 0:int(cols/2)] = 0
    
    try:
        updated_depth_msg = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_depth, "16UC1")
        updated_depth_msg.header = depth_data.header
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        self.depth_pub.publish(updated_depth_msg)
```

Once you set the header, please confirm it by executing the following command:

```
rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_converted | head
```

Furthermore, please ensure the header values, such as `frame_id`, etc., in the converted image are the same as in the raw image. For example, you can use the following command to see the header for the raw image:

```
rostopic echo -n 1 /camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw | head
```

---

Originally posted by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) with karma: 1744 on 2022-08-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [iHany](https://answers.ros.org/users/92871/ihany/) on 2022-08-25**:
Thank you for answering!
However, I found that `self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg` cannot receive header with the following error (also see [this](http://docs.ros.org/en/lunar/api/cv_bridge/html/python/index.html#cv_bridge.CvBridge.cv2_to_imgmsg)).

```
[ERROR] [1661487463.445747]: bad callback: <bound method DepthConverter.callback of <__main__.DepthConverter object at 0x7fde4de54c88>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 750, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "depth_converter.py", line 39, in callback
    cv_depth, encoding="passthrough", header=depth_data.header,
TypeError: cv2_to_imgmsg() got an unexpected keyword argument 'header'
```

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2022-08-25**:
You can assign it manually. Please see the updated answer above.

**Comment by [iHany](https://answers.ros.org/users/92871/ihany/) on 2022-08-25**:
Gotcha. I could update the header as follows.

```
    depth_data_pub = self.bridge.cv2_to_imgmsg(cv_depth, "passthrough")
    depth_data_pub.header = depth_data.header
    self.depth_pub.publish(depth_data_pub)
```